# Retrieve data from MongoDB ISODate field with Spring-Boot 2.0.1 with restTemplate

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I can't retrieve the correct data from ISOdate field from my MongoDB table.

At my MongoDb collection my field dtInicio have the value :

```
{"dtInicio" : ISODate("2018-07-01T00:00:00.000+0000")}
```

and after execute mongoTemplated query

```
Query query = new Query();       
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("cp").is(cpValue));
List<Vo> list = mongoTemplate.find(query,Vo.class,COLLECTION);
Vo vo = list.get(0);
Date dt = vo.getDataInicio();
```

I get the the wrong value in dt variable.

getDataInicio() returns the wrong value : 
    "Sat Jun 30 21:00:00 BRT 2018"

but in the collection field (dtInicio) has another value : 
    "(ISODate("2018-07-01T00:00:00.000+0000"))"

My POJO Vo was annotated with:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING,pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@JsonProperty("inicio")
@DateTimeFormat(style="yyyy-MM-dd")
@Field("dtInicio")
private Date dataInicio;
```

Why my query return wrong value? I expected 2018-07-01 00:00:00 and not 2018-06-30 21:00:00

Tks Guys ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue I need to include "locale" and "timezone" in my POJO fields :

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING,pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd",
                                            locale = "pt-BR", 
                                            timezone = "Brazil/East")
@JsonProperty("inicio")
@Field("dtInicio")
private Date dataInicio;
```

Answer (score 0):

the two are the same...in different timezone. You can either store your date with right timezone (BRT) or format your result in GMT timezone.

Comment: Tks .... I tried this using "spring.jackson.time-zone: America/Sao_Paulo" in applications.properties, but the problem is the same ....

Comment: did you store a new record from your new configured app? because your result display already was in America/Sao_paulo.

Comment: Hi  @matthPen   ... I did this ... I used the same values to the new record. When I retrieved this value I got the same wrong value in my POJO.